# Getting the contact point when using OverlapCapsule

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I am trying to use `OverlapCapsuleNonAlloc` to determine all enemy weapons that intersect with my character's `CapsuleCollider` at the same time. I want to get the contact point to trigger vfx in the right place.
Is there someway I can find the contact point using OverlapCapsuleNonAlloc in Unity ?

Comment: When two shapes intersect in 3d space, then you don't have one single contact point. You have a whole 3d volume of overlapping space. So what you want can not work on a conceptual level.

Comment: @Philipp i'm not sure if i understand well, but i did read somewhere that an OverlapSphere for example is just a bunch of Raycast, so normally it should be possible to get the hit Point, as Raycasting gives you that

Comment: I don't know where you read that, but I doubt that this is true. For collision detection between most 3d shapes there are far more efficient algorithms. But if you want to determine contact points, you can of course use your own raycasts. But then you of course need to decide from which point within your 3d volume you want to cast your ray(s).

Comment: Have you considered using [Collider.ClosestPoiint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.ClosestPoint.html) to choose the point on the weapon's collider that's closest to your capsule's center? It's not directly a contact point in most cases, but it gives you a good clue about the region of overlap.

Comment: @DMGregory yea, i was thinking of it and was too hesitant in case 10 ennemies attack at the same time it might be not good to go. but, since you think too its likely to work, i'll just try that.
I'll answer back my question if that works well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`overlapResults[i].ClosestPoint(yourGameObject.position)` works pretty well, but consider specifying the Layer you are targeting in your overlap ^^